# conda install slows down 2-3x intermittently

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Newbie to conda.

We have a build system that uses `conda install`. We have noticed that the `conda install` slows down about 4x intermittently (https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9768).

I am looking for pointers to debug as well any fixes/tuning we should perform if this is a known issue.

Thanks in advance,
Kiran

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment?

Comment: I updated the issue to point to a more recent issue on github with details (https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9768)